# Getting a Specific Date Range

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I need to get a date range starting last Wednesday to yesterday. This program is run on every Wednesday. Is it the good way to do it? What if the program is run on a Tuesday for some reason? How do I make it work? Thanks.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
Date transactionBeginDate = calendar.getTime();


calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
Date transactionEndDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the DAY_OF_WEEK value on the calendar.

Something like ...

```
while(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK != Calendar.WEDNESDAY){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
}
Date transactionBeginDate = calendar.getTime();
```

If you do this on a Thursday you'll end up getting your start and end dates as the same day. You should be able to better tweak it to your liking though.

### edit

If you wanted to get a whole week regardless of when the program is run then I think you want to start with your end date and then get your start date...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//Find last Wednesday to act as end date
while(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK != Calendar.WEDNESDAY){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
}
Date transactionEndDate = calendar.getTime();
//Go back one week from that Wednesday to get start date.
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
Date transactionStartDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: +1, exactly what I was about to type. This is how I do it in a program I just wrote that deals with weekly data objects. Although one thing, I am not 100% sure the month will roll over when you increment beyond the last(or first) day. But I know that the year field does this so I would assume the months do too. But if you are worried or you discover the months do not roll over automatically, you can add to the DAY_OF_YEAR field.

Comment: @gnomed I'm pretty sure the DAY_OF_MONTH will automatically roll over to the previous month. Calendar is pretty smart about this things.

Comment: Ya, I thought as much since I definitely tested it for the year property. I just never had a reason to test it with the month, but I imagine you are correct. BTW: The reason I was testing in the first place was because the app was supporting java 1.3 and I wasnt sure how it was implemented there.

Comment: @Shaded It is pretty smart. From the javadoc "Overflow occurs when a field value exceeds its range and, as a result, the next larger field is incremented or decremented and the field value is adjusted back into its range."

Comment: How do you get the date of last Wednesday regardless of when the program is asking for? If the program asks on a wednesday, it will still give you the date of last wednesday?

Comment: @Milli Saboski so regardless of what day the program is run you always want a full week of data? meaning if it was run today (Thursday) it would pull all data for 3/23 - 3/30 and if it was pulled 3/29 it would then get 3/16 - 3/23?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Milli Edits made that should help!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html) feature of Joda-Time. If you need to use dates in Java, you should just bite the bullet and learn Joda-Time now. It will save you a ton of headache later.